# Strange behavior of isset and empty function

Tags: php

I am running into strange problem. I have following simple line in PHP

```
<?php
    echo "Value = ".$this->language; //outputs Value = en
    echo "<br>isset = ".isset($this->language);  //Outputs isset = 
    echo "<br>Is empty = ".empty($this->language);  //Outputs Is empty= 1 
?>
```

Why is that the second line doesn't prints `true` or '1' and third line prints its empty, when its clear from first line that `this->language` is set and is not empty??

Comment: Can you show the output of `print_r($this->language);`?

Comment: @RaxWeber, it prints `en`

Comment: Then there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Are you sure that `language` is an actual member of your class ? It may be retrieved from an internal array which is accessed by the __get magic method ?

Comment: @LucasDelobelle is right.. If you use __get magic method then you must implement the __isset magic method as well

Comment: @LucasDelobelle, yes it is. And those three lines come simultaneously after each other.

Comment: @LucasDelobelle, actually `language` is a variable of the `parent class`. And the code I posted is written in `child class`

Comment: Have a look at the answer given. `empty()` returns false if it isn't empty. That's quite logical don't you think?

Comment: @icecub, but `empty` is returning true, even its not empty

Comment: Ah right, my bad. In that case you should check if you overloaded the variable inside your class. `__get` and `__set` are needed to access the variable unless it's public. Though I'm not sure if setting it public is enough..

Comment: if $this->language have the value so your condition is become false beacuse your have value en. so its show ouput empty . logic works quite

Comment: How is the `language` attribute declared in the parent class and what is its scope exactly ? Should be at least protected

Comment: @LucasDelobelle in parent class its declared as `private`

Comment: @JYoThI if `$this->language` has value, then `isset` should return true, and `empty` should return `false`, so where logic is working?

Comment: So set it as protected ? If it is private the child class should not be able to access it !

Comment: @LucasDelobelle but child class can access its value, setting it as `protected` didn't work either

Comment: That's not normal that child class can access its value...if the member is set to private in parent class, then in child class `echo $this->language;` should throw an 'Undefined property' error. This makes no sense, I think we're missing some information. Did you implement magic methods, like __get() for instance, or did you overload the language attribute in the child class ? I'm running out of clues to be honest.

Comment: Show us a complete reproducible example. Some code that we can run to come to the same result. It's clearly some problem with magic methods or property visibility, but we cannot see your class implementation, so we're just taking stabs into the dark.

Answer (score 1):

instead of 'echo' use var_dump.Will help you to understand the difference.

```
$language = 'en';
echo "Value = ".$language; //outputs Value = en
$isset = isset($language);
$empty = empty($language);
echo "<br>isset = ";;  
var_dump($isset); //bool(true)
echo "<br>Is empty = ";  
var_dump($empty); // bool(false)
```

Comment: first line returns `string(2) "en"`, second line returns `bool(false) ` and third line returns `bool(true) `, so that means this didn't help me either

Comment: @WatsMyName may be it did not help you but its correct and expected behaviour

Comment: isset() check whether value is set or not? & empty() Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist. for more details. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

Below Code Snippet should help you

If the Variable is declared as private in parent class it will not be available in the child class , it has to be either protected or private

```
class base {
   // changed to protected
   protected $language = 'en';
}

class child extends base {

  public function spit(){
     echo "Value = ".$this->language; //outputs Value = en
     echo "<br>isset = ".isset($this->language);  //Outputs isset = 
     echo "<br>Is empty = ".empty($this->language);  //Outputs Is empty= 1 
   }
}
$ch = new child();
$ch->spit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for **isset()** is as below.

`isset($this->language)` will always echo 'false'. because the isset() accepts VARIABLES as it's parameters, but in this case, `$this->language` is NOT a VARIABLE. it is a VALUE returned from the __get() method of the class. Thus the `isset($this->language)` expression will always equal 'false'.
Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Explanation for **empty()** is as below.

```
class Registry
{
    //Definition goes here
}
$registry = new Registry();
$registry->empty = '';
$registry->notEmpty = 'not empty';

var_dump(empty($registry->empty)); // true, so far so good
var_dump(empty($registry->notEmpty)); // true, .. say what?
$tmp = $registry->notEmpty;
var_dump(empty($tmp)); // false as expected
```

The result for empty($registry->notEmpty) is a bit unexpected as the value is obviously set and non-empty. This is due to the fact that the empty() function uses __isset() magic function in these cases.
Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code is very complex, the code I was working on with is built with `Silverstripe`. But i found a dirty workaround that will work on plain PHP as well.

in parent class, i created a method which checks if language is set, like this

```
public function isLanguageEmpty(){
        return isset($this->language);
    }
```

and in child class we can simply use `$this->isLanguageEmpty()`

But to understand what might be the actual problem, the comments in original post and the other answers will be helpful.